# Group by statement not working with Select Case

Tags: sql, select, group-by, pivot, case

```
SELECT ZRECNROOT,
       CASE
         WHEN ZSPIDCAT = 'VEN_NAME_1' THEN
          ZSPIDENT
       END as VEN_NAME,
       CASE
         WHEN ZSPIDCAT = 'VENDOR_ID' THEN
          ZSPIDENT
       END as VENDORID
  FROM T1
```

I have written this SQL statement which is giving data like below

```
 ZRECNROOT VEN_NAME VENDORID 
 123       ABC      ? 
 123       ?        12345
```

Now I want to merge these records using group by RECNROOT but group by is throwing error here.

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown due to the non-aggregated columns `ZSPIDCAT` and `ZSPIDENT`. So, you need an extra aggregation along with `GROUP`ing `BY` `ZRECNROOT` such as

```
SELECT ZRECNROOT,
       MAX(CASE
         WHEN ZSPIDCAT = 'VEN_NAME_1' THEN
          ZSPIDENT
       END) as VEN_NAME,
       MAX(CASE
         WHEN ZSPIDCAT = 'VENDOR_ID' THEN
          ZSPIDENT
       END) as VENDORID
  FROM T1
 GROUP BY ZRECNROOT
```

where `MAX()` or `MIN()` aggregation might have non-numeric arguments unlike to some others such as `AVG()`, `SUM()` ..etc.